# Choosing Select Columns in Oracle INSERT ALL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an `INSERT ALL` statement in Oracle to insert data into two different tables. The data is coming from a rather complex subquery rather than a `VALUES` clause.

My issue is that I don't want to insert **all** the columns returned by the subquery into both tables.

As a simple example, suppose I have two tables `tab1` and `tab2` each containing three columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.

Now suppose  my subquery returns a single row with the values `A`, `B` and `C`.

So, I want `A`, `B` and `C` inserted into `col1`, `col2` and `col3` of `tab1` respectively, but I want, say, only `A` and `C` to go into `col1` and `col3` of `tab2`.

My statement would look something like this:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO tab1
  (col1, col2, col3)
INTO tab2
  (col1, ?, col3)
FROM
( ...
 complex subquery which returns A, B, C
  ...
)
```

Is there a way I can use some sort of a 'filler' or 'garbage column' to allow me to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO tab1
  (col1, col2, col3) values (a, b, c)
INTO tab2
  (col1, col3) values (a, c)
SELECT a, b, c
FROM
( ...
 complex subquery which returns A, B, C
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

this syntax is possible

```
INSERT ALL
INTO ap_cust(f1, f2) VALUES (a, d)
INTO ap_orders(f1, f2, f3) VALUES (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c,d
FROM table;
```

see http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without the `values` clauses?

Comment: @Isaac, without the `values` clauses, how would it know which columns from the select to assign to each column in the target tables?